# How to use $sample with geo near in mongodb with PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to run a query that allows to find nearby users given a certain maximum distance. I would like that after finding them, it would randomly take 10 documents among those found and I don't know how to do it.
i tried using $sample but i got several misuse errors. how should i do?

code:

```js
$result = ["coordinate"=> [
     '$near'=> [
       '$geometry'=> [
          "type"=> "Point" ,
          "coordinates" => [ 12.099700 , 45.267670 ]
       ],
       '$maxDistance'=> 40000
     ]
   ]];
```

thanks!

Comment: What are the misuse errors that you received?  What was the full query that you executed?

Comment: i tried this:  $result = ["coordinate"=> [
     '$near'=> [
       '$geometry'=> [
          "type"=> "Point" ,
          "coordinates" => [ 12.099700 , 45.267670 ]
       ],
       '$maxDistance'=> 40000
     ],
  '$sample' => 10
   ]];       but i got "invalid argument in geo near query: $sample"

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, you are attempting to nest [the `$sample` aggregation stage](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/) underneath the `coordinate` filter alongside the `$near` operator:

```
[
    "coordinate"=> [ 
        '$near'=>  [ 
            '$geometry'=> [ 
                "type"=> "Point" , "coordinates" => [ 12.099700 , 45.267670 ]
            ], 
            '$maxDistance'=> 40000 
        ], 
        '$sample' => 10 
    ]
]
```

This is not correct syntax. To use the `$sample` aggregation stage, you'll want to change your code to use [the aggregate() method](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/php-library/current/tutorial/crud/#complex-queries-with-aggregation) and then structure the pipeline accordingly. The first stage to do the filtering (prior to the `$sample`) should probably be a [`$geoNear` stage](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) (rather than a [`$match` stage](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) which is commonly first) per one of the restrictions noted [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#restrictions).

This overlaps a lot with [your other question on the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73866376/find-close-people-who-liked-x-person-using-geo-near-from-mongodb-and-php) where similar advice will apply.

Comment: premise:  i'm a beginner with mongodb. i tried to do this:      $command = new MongoDB\Driver\Command([
    'aggregate' => 'utente',
    'pipeline' => [
        '$geoNear'=> [
   'near'=> [ 'type'=> "Point", 'coordinates'=> [12.099700 , 45.267670] ],
   'distanceField'=> "dist.calculated",
   'maxDistance'=> 50000,
   'includeLocs'=> "dist.coordinate",
   'spherical'=> true
   ]
    ],
]);               but i got 'pipeline' option must be specified as an array . i don't know how to structure it. could you give me some help?