# find close people who liked x person using geo near from mongodb and php

Tags: php, mongodb

I wanted to ask if there is a way to get people around first of all (and here I did) and then check if x person has already liked (individual) users around him. if x person has already liked that user then exclude him from the query, otherwise include him and show him.

i tried to do this

```js
$result = ["coordinate"=> [
     '$near'=> [
       '$geometry'=> [
          "type"=> "Point" ,
          "coordinates" => [ 12.099700 , 45.267670 ]
       ],
       '$maxDistance'=> 40000
     ],
     ['$lookup'=>
     [
       'from'=> "like",
       'localField'=> "username",
       'foreignField'=> "username",
       'as'=> "FROM"
     ]],
     ['$lookup'=>
     [
       'from'=> "like",
       'localField'=> "username",
       'foreignField'=> "likeTo",
       'as'=> "TO"
     ]]
   ]];
```

but didn't work.

Note: I have a many to many pattern and therefore I use two lookup (always if that's correct).

Structure:

User(username, ....)

Like(username, likeTo, ...)

thanks!

Comment: What didn't work with your attempt? Was there an error message, or incorrect results (how so), or?

Comment: executing that code i got " invalid argument in geo near query: 0"